# Comparing passwords to stored hash

Tags: php, php-password-hash

From my understanding so far (at least I think) the password_hash() function generates a hash based on the algorithm in use, cost and the salt. While the password_verify uses the information provided from e.g. `password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost'=>10))` to check if the retuned value is true or false as it contains all the information necessary for verifying.

I previously used

`$SQL_Query = "SELECT * FROM DB_Table WHERE userName = '".$username."'" AND password = $ID;`

which would work as they were stored in plain text and could return true whereas logically it won't work this time around.

I have came across similar questions where they use static passwords in explanations such as

```
<?php

$to_verify = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $to_verify)) 
{
    echo 'Password is valid!';

} else 
{
    echo 'Wrong password.';
}
```

The concept I am having trouble understanding is how one would check the password input against the hashed value if it is stored in a database rather than the being known by the page at that point in time? I recently got help regarding storing the values which was a silly error on my part but I guess this isn't clicking with me as well as I hoped for the moment.

Comment: You have to query for the hash by selecting the user. Once you have the hash you can compare to the posted password, [testing for true as you have done above](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: you've a syntax error `userName = '".$username."'"` <= right there. *"which would work"* I doubt that. The extra double quote shouldn't be there. Tell us that's a typo.

Comment: @Dagon Possible duplicate of many. Too many Q&A's around to fill this question.

Comment: trouble understanding the question and why the question. If you're having trouble inserting and checking against a stored hash in db, then that's an easy one.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the examples for `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` *together.*

The hash-string that's produced by `password_hash` is self-describing: it incorporates an indication of both the algorithm and the random-salt that was used.  `password_verify` knows about all this. It knows how to "do the right thing" for passwords both recent and vintage.

Therefore, simply query the database to get the *(hashed ...)* password for this user.  Then, use `password_verify()` to see if this hash-value matches this password-value.

You can't query for the user-name `AND password` at the same time.  Query only for the user-name, get the hashed value, and use `password_verify()` to check it.

Answer (score 0):

> the hash is generated randomly each time

No, the hash is always the same for a given input, salt value and iterations through which the hash algorithm is run (which is controlled by the cost parameter).

> The concept I am having trouble understanding is how one would check the password input against the hashed value if it is stored in a database rather than the being known by the page at that point in time?

You would check the password input at login time, using the password provided by the user, and the salt and potentially number of times to apply the hash algorithm associated with that user.  Once the password check is successful, use a session or other mechanism to keep the user logged in.

Comment: The hash is always different for a given input if you allow PHP to provide a random salt each time.

Comment: Yes you need to store the salt for a given user.

Comment: *"Yes you need to store the salt for a given user"* - why not just let the function take care of it?